# Is it possible to create a new image standard which supports privacy?

Tags: privacy, image

After watching a TED video on [sexting](https://www.ted.com/talks/amy_adele_hasinoff_how_to_practice_safe_sexting), I heard about that 17 years old girl who committed suicide because her boyfriend shared her private pictures in their school.
I wondered if it is possible to create a new standard image format which takes into account the privacy issues. Basically thinking, it may add another piece of EXIF data which defines the forward ability or number of times the image can be forwarded to anyone else. Or a number of times that image can be seen, like self-destructing image after one view. For the digital rights, a unique ID can be coded into the image which may be able to trace it to some degree. I don't know how to prevent screenshots.

This kind of privacy related data should be non-editable for the end user. I know it's almost impossible but at least operating system built in prevention may prevent many incidents.

Comment: What about if I took a picture of my screen? Not even a screenshot, just took a picture of it. Or was streaming the screen elsewhere. Or manipulated the exif data? Doesn't sound like it'd be hart to circumvent this.

Comment: Yes, it is very easy to circumvent this. It maybe only hardening and may prevent some people. I am just brainstorming here. Maybe we can display image in a way that is only visible to human eye, invisible to cameras.

Comment: @ozgur Although it is a technical problem, it requires a social solution. Teach students to be more respectful towards other people's privacy.

Comment: One of the newer social media platforms (snapchat?) sold itself as having this level of security and it was quickly defeated by screenshotting software. S.L. Barth is right--  sometimes personal responsibility is the only real solution. Not every problem warrants (or is solved by) a technical solution.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Teaching students to be more respectful is of very limited value, since it only takes one person not respectful to screw someone over. Instead, you should teach people how not to put themselves into a situation that they may regret in the first place. After all, which is better, teaching blackhat hackers not to break into things, or teaching sysadmins how to secure their systems?

Answer (score 5):

If you can read it, you can copy it. This is why all attempts at copy-protection are doomed from the start.

You can make it harder for the end user to forward it, like in the scheme you suggest. But somebody will build a custom version of the OS and modify it to ignore the EXIF note that forbids forwarding.

If nothing else, a user can always take a picture of the phone while it is displaying the picture.

So - no, a standard like that is not feasible. From a technology perspective, the best you can do is make it harder, but people will always find and use ways to evade it.